# Matching prepared SQL statement parameters with bind_param variables

Tags: php, mysqli

"Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement"...

I've had look at many of the questions on this error, and I can't understand where I'm going wrong with this. I'm trying to get a row from the database and display the records in my existing form so that it can be edited and saved. I've checked that there are 30 parameters in the SQL statement, and 30 variables in the $stmt->bind_param. Can someone point me in the right direction with this, here is my code so far:

```
// get the record from database - (30 parameters in mysql statement)
if ($stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id, start_date, company, stock_code, card_quantity, fiske_print, carrier_quantity, quoted, quote_details, quoted_date, quote_accepted, quote_accepted_date, proof_sent, proof_sent_date,proof_approved, proof_approved_date, printed, print_date, closed_loop_allocated, invoiced, invoiced_date, posted, tracking_number, postal_date, paid, is_bulk_load, bulk_funds_received, cards_loaded, notes, completed FROM jobs WHERE id = ?")) {
    // 30 "s"'s - 30 $values
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss", $id,$start_date,$company,$stock_code,$card_quantity,$fiske_print,$carrier_quantity,$quoted,$quote_details,$quote_date,$quote_accepted,$quote_accepted_date,$proof_sent,$proof_sent_date,$proof_approved,$proof_approved_date,$printed,$printed_date,$closed_loop_allocated,$invoiced,$invoice_date,$posted,$tracking_number,$postal_date,$paid,$is_bulk_load,$bulk_funds_received,$cards_loaded,$notes,$completed);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id,$start_date,$company,$stock_code,$card_quantity,$fiske_print,$carrier_quantity,$quoted,$quote_details,$quote_date,$quote_accepted,$quote_accepted_date,$proof_sent,$proof_sent_date,$proof_approved,$proof_approved_date,$printed,$printed_date,$closed_loop_allocated,$invoiced,$invoice_date,$posted,$tracking_number,$postal_date,$paid,$is_bulk_load,$bulk_funds_received,$cards_loaded,$notes,$completed);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // show the form
    renderForm(NULL, $id,$start_date,$company,$stock_code,$card_quantity,$fiske_print,$carrier_quantity,$quoted,$quote_details,$quote_date,$quote_accepted,$quote_accepted_date,$proof_sent,$proof_sent_date,$proof_approved,$proof_approved_date,$printed,$printed_date,$closed_loop_allocated,$invoiced,$invoice_date,$posted,$tracking_number,$postal_date,$paid,$is_bulk_load,$bulk_funds_received,$cards_loaded,$notes,$completed);

    echo 'We are about to edit an existing job ' . $id;

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only parameter you need to bind is the id your searching on not the fields your selecting

```
if ($stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id, start_date, company, stock_code, card_quantity, fiske_print, carrier_quantity, quoted, quote_details, quoted_date, quote_accepted, quote_accepted_date, proof_sent, proof_sent_date,proof_approved, proof_approved_date, printed, print_date, closed_loop_allocated, invoiced, invoiced_date, posted, tracking_number, postal_date, paid, is_bulk_load, bulk_funds_received, cards_loaded, notes, completed FROM jobs WHERE id = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @MikeA is id really a string? they are usually integers

Comment: yes id is an integer. Because there are many columns, my way of trying to work through this was to firstly just treat every record as a string in an attempt to lessen the confusion slightly...

Comment: @MikeA tweaked above to use i for integer.

Comment: You can also used named parameters and bind those, which can make life easier when you have a query with many parameters.  For instance, you could use the query `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = :id` with the PHP statement `$stmt->bind_param(':id', $id);`.  See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php